# React Native error: "Failed to compile Syntax Error None of these files exist: "

Tags: react-native

I'm taking a React Native tutorial and I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to compile
Syntax Error

None of these files exist: 

*..\..\..\..\..\.src\screens\ListScreen(.native|ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|tsx|ios.js|native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|native.json|.json)

*..\..\..\..\..\.src\screens\ListScreen\index(.native|ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|tsx|ios.js|native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|native.json|.json)
```

There are only three files being imported into my App.js file and the error shows when I import ListScreen from ".src/screens/ListScreen".  When I comment out that line the error goes away.  I have no idea what's causing it.

Below is the code from the four JS files and the folder structure.  It's a course on Udemy and no one else has encountered it so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since all the other files were authored by the instructor which I downloaded at the beginning of the course.

**App.js**

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ComponentsScreen from "./src/screens/ComponentsScreen";
import ListScreen from ".src/screens/ListScreen";

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Components: ComponentsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Components",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "App",
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return <Text style={styles.text}>ProjectWherewoof</Text>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

**ComponentsScreen.js**

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const ComponentsScreen = () => {
    const greeting = <Text>Getting Started with React Native</Text>;
    const myname = 'Arturo';

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.greetingStyle}>{greeting}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.nameStyle}>My name is {myname} !!!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  greetingStyle: {
    fontSize: 45,
  },
 nameStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
  }
});

export default ComponentsScreen;
```

**ListScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ListScreen = () => {
  return <Text>List Screen</Text>;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ListScreen;
```

**Folder Structure:**
[Folder Structure snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhsyf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a slash in `import ListScreen from ".src/screens/ListScreen";`. `.src` is not a directory in your project.

It should be `import ListScreen from "./src/screens/ListScreen";` (or just `"src/screens/ListScreen";`)

Comment: That was it!  ughh is there a condition where if you stare at a screen long enough you end up too drunk to think straight?  Like with a campfire?

Comment: We've all been there.  If my answer helped feel free to accept it or if you solved it your own way feel free to answer and accept that!